# Multiple "agents" handling a single array

Tags: php, arrays

Apologies if this has been covered before - I did my searching but possibly may not know the correct terms to have used.

This process is handled with PHP.

Here's the situation:

I have a large array of file names.  The script I have opens these files and enters their content into a database.  Processing these files one at a time takes over 24 hours, and these files are updated on a daily basis.

Breaking the single large array into four smaller arrays and running concurrent processes  finishes the job before the 24 hour window elapses, but sometimes one or two processes will finish hours before the others because file sizes vary on a daily basis.

Much like people who stock retail shelves (who else has worked that nightmare before?) pitch in to help out with what's left after finishing their own tasks, I'd like to have a script in place where these "agents" do the same.

Here's some basics of what I have figured out - it could be wrong, and I'm not too proud to protest if I am :-)

```
$files = array('file1','file2','file3','file4','file5'); 
//etc... on to over 4k elements

while($file = array_pop($files)){

    //Something in here...  I have no idea what.

}
```

Ideas?  Something like four function calls or four loops within that overarching 'while' has crossed my mind, but I'm pretty sure it's going to wait on executing subsequent calls until the previous one(s) finish.

Any help is appreciated.  I'm seriously stuck on this one!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with PHP? Use the language of your choice that supports easy multithreading (like ThreadPool in C#)

Comment: Python..... Maybe the answer here

Comment: It's the language I'm most familiar with, and the code for grabbing the source files is written in PHP, but it's run from a bash console instead of a website - so some shell scripting is entirely within the realm of possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database-backed message queue seems the obvious solution but I think that's overkill in this case. I would simply put the files to be processed into a single dedicated queue directory, then use the DirectoryIterator class to scan it. Something like this:

```
while (true) {
    look in the queue directory for a file
    if you don't fine one, exit the script, all processing is done
    if you find one, rename it or move it to a work directory
    if the rename/move command succeeded, process the file
    if the rename/move command failed, one of the other threads got it first
}
```

Edit:

Regarding launching the workers, you could use a simple shell script to spawn the PHP processes in the background:

```
NUM_WORKERS=5
for WORKER in $(seq 1 ${NUM_WORKERS})
do
    echo "starting worker ${WORKER}"
    php -f /path/to/my/process.php &
done
```

Then, create a cron entry to run this launcher, for example, at midnight:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/launcher.sh
```

Comment: I like this because it builds upon what I already have (all target files are downloaded to a single directory before processing into the DB), but the only way I can think of to make it do what I want would be to have a shell or perl script which executes background processes (adding a & at the end of the command) and is able to determine when the process finishes, thereby assigning new files to the available "agents".  Shell scripting and Perl are beyond me right now, though.  It's on my "to do" list, though :-)

Comment: You wouldn't assign files to agents with this. The agents would look for more files to process and quit if there are none. The master script would just start four (or ten) agents.

Comment: Hmm...  So this is more of a, say, "distribution facility"?  (for lack of a better anaogy).  This runs on a target directory which then scans, say, four other directories for the presence of files.  If a directory is empty, it moves a file into it.  Each of those folders are monitored by a separate process which enters the contents of any file in that directory into the DB?  Am I even close?  I don't think I've had enough coffee yet this morning...

Comment: @user1075581: I've added an analogy to my answer that might help you understand Alex's queue and message queues in general. You're sort of correct, except that there aren't four directories being monitored.

Comment: There's just one directory. Think of it as a big box filled with balls, and you have some workers to put them away. You instruct the workers simply, "If there are no balls in the box, take a five minute nap. If there are balls in the box, take one and put it away. Repeat forever." Every worker has the same instructions, so you don't have one worker for red balls and one for blue. Thus, if you get a bigger box, you just add some more workers, no new instructions needed.

Comment: Okay, back at the computer and I'm really liking what I'm seeing here!  I'll be giving this a test run soon to see it in action!

Comment: All right - I've had enough time to play around with it to not really get it working 100%, but enough to know that this is definitely the answer I'm looking for.  Using the code you provided (thanks!) and building out the process.php file, everything is running as I'd like it to, except that the numerous processes are all grabbing the same files.  I just need to write into the PHP to move/rename/something the files being used by each process and it will be golden.  Thanks Alex! :-D

Comment: Right, this is what the rename is for. Note that the rename() function returns true on success. So you call rename() and if it returns true, then you know you have a unique lock on the file and you process the file using the new name. (You could do something like just stick a ".lock" on the end of the filename.) If the rename() returns false then somebody beat you to it, and you move on.

Comment: Initial testing using dummy files and echos instead of calling the database insert functions were pretty dang successful.  I'll be giving it a "real world run" soon - just need the current process to finish (which should be within the hour).  That, of course, after backing up the DB to recover in case it all goes to hell! :-P

Comment: There was a bit of a delay while I did some troubleshooting, but it's running now, and it's running BEAUTIFULLY.  Thanks again for your help! :-D

Answer (score 2):

You want what's called a "message queue". Something like [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/)

You'll basically create a list of messages that include your individual filenames. You'll then create a set of processors to process them. Each processor will handle one file then go back to the queue to see if there are more messages/files waiting to be processed.

EDIT:
Here's an analogy to help explain message queues. Your first idea is like a human manager taking a stack of files, dividing them into four piles and then handing each of his four employees a pile to process. A message queue is more like this: the manager puts all the files on a table and tells each employee to take a single file from the table and process it. He tells them when they're done with the first file to keep taking files until there are no more files on the table. When all the files are done, the employees can go home.

One employee might end up with really large files and only handle a few, while another employee might get smaller files and handle many. It doesn't matter how many each employee handles, they'll all keep working until the table is empty.

Comment: I'll need to read up on this some more before determining if it's what I need or not.  @alex-howansky mentioned a solution that processes files in a directory, and that's pretty much in line with what I already have in place, but as for code that executes processes in parallel instead of serial, I'm still a little stuck (hence the desire to look further into beanstalkd).

Comment: "Message queue" is a good search term. It's a general idea and not limited to beanstalkd, which is one particular implementation. For Alex's implementation of the queue, you can have one php or bash script that moves all the files into the queue directory. Then it would start a bunch of separate php scripts that follow the pseudocode he provided. Those scripts would run simultaneously handling the files in the queue. That's still a "message queue", just a simpler code-it-yourself version.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a socket server master script that hands out file paths to x number of slave scripts, until there are no files left to process. This way, all the slave scripts will keep running, and you can hand out file paths dynamically as they are requested.

Something like this:

**master.php**

```
<?php

  // load the array of files to process (however you do this)
  $fileList = file('filelist.txt');

  // Create a listening socket on localhost
  $serverSocket = stream_socket_server('tcp://127.0.0.1:7878');
  $sockets = array($serverSocket);
  $clients = array();

  // Loop while there are still files to process
  while (count($fileList)) {

    // Run a select() call on the existing sockets' read buffers
    // Skip to next iteration if no sockets are waiting for handling
    if (stream_select($read = $sockets, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 1) < 1) {
      continue;
    }

    // Loop sockets with data to read
    foreach ($read as $socket) {

      if ($socket == $serverSocket) {
        // Accept new clients
        $sockets[] = $clients[] = stream_socket_accept($serverSocket);
      } else if (trim(fgets($socket)) == 'next') {
        // Hand out a new file path to the client
        fwrite($socket, array_shift($fileList)."\n");
        if (!count($fileList)) {
          break 2;
        }
      }

    }

  }

  // When we're done, disconnect the clients
  foreach ($clients as $socket) {
    @fclose($socket);
  }

  // ...and close the listen socket
  @fclose($serverSocket);
```

**slave.php**

```
<?php

  $socket = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 7878);

  while (!feof($socket)) {

    // Get a new file path from the master
    fwrite($socket,"next\n");
    $path = trim(fgets($socket));

    if (is_file($path)) {
      // Process the file at $path here
    }

  }
```

You then just need to start *master.php*, then when it is running, you can start however many instances of *slave.php* as you want, and they will all keep running until there are no more files to process.

Obviously, this has no error handling, but it should provide a basic framework to get you started. This relies on blocking function calls (`stream_select()` and `fgets()`) to avoid a race condition - this may or may not be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: That is something significantly more clever than I could have ever come up with on my own!  I like the concept!  It will be a bit before I'm able to try it out, however - getting ready to head out for a bit.  Nice, though!  :-D